# invalid use of non-static member function al compilar

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente programa donde hago una serie de ejercicios de recursividad: recientemente me encontraba implementando la función de `ExisteElemento(int n[], int x, int i)`; a esta función le doy los siguientes `parametros (bigaux,0, ingreso_g())`. Al momento de compilar, netbeans me muestra lo siguiente...

```
undefined reference to `Ej::ExisteElemento(int*, int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Creo que el error se origina del uso de `ingreso_g()` en los parámetros, pero esto me confunde ya que utilicé este misma función para *Ocurrencia* con los siguientes parámetros `(ingreso_g(),0)`.

Anexo el código mencionado.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

/*Escriban una función recursiva llamada ExisteElement o que verifique si un elemento x se encuentra en una lista L. 
 * Escriban una función recursiva llamada Ocurrencia que cuente la cantidad de ocurrencias de un elemento x en una lista L. 
Escriban una función recursiva llamada Suma que retorne la suma de los elementos de una lista de enteros L. 
Escriban una función recursiva llamada OrdenarLista que ordene una lista L. 
 */
class Ej
{
private:
    vector<int> P_array;
    int N;
    
public:
    Ej();
    void SetN(int n);
    int getN();
    void SetArray(int n[]);
    void get_Assign_Array(int n[]);//LE ASIGNA LOS VALORES DE P_ARRAY A UN ARREGLO o. 0
    void getArray();//IMPRIME EL ARREGLO, EN TEORIA NO SE PUEDE REGRESAR UN ARREGLO DE ENTERO ´•͜ •`
    void Proc_princ();
    void ingreso_arreglo();//FUNCION QUE ASIGNA LOS VALORES INGRESADOS AL ARREGLO (ᴗ.ᴗ)
    int menu();
    int ingreso_g();
    int Suma(int array[], int x);
    int Ocurrencia(int n, int posicInc);
    int ExisteElemento(int n [],int x,int i);
};

Ej::Ej(){}
void Ej::SetN(int n)
{
    N=n;
}
int Ej::getN()
{
    return N;
}
int Ej::ingreso_g()
{
    bool b1=false,b2=false,b3=false;
    int aux;
    char s[50]="";
    do
    {
    cout<<"INGRESE EL NUMERO A BUSCAR/CONTAR OCURENCIA..."<<endl<<">"; cin.getline(s,55);
    if(s[0]>=64 && s[0]<=90) b2=true;
    if(s[0]>=97 && s[0]<=122) b3=true;
    if(b2 || b3)
      {
      cout<<endl<<"VALOR INTRODUCIDO DE ORIGEN NO NUMERICO, INTRODUZCA UN ENTERO VALIDO...."<<endl;
      b1=true;
      }
    aux=atoi(s);
    if(aux!=0) b1=false;
    b2=false;
    b3=false;
    }while(b1);
    return(atoi(s));
}

void Ej::get_Assign_Array(int n[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        n[i]=P_array[i];
    }
}

void Ej::getArray()
{
    cout<<endl<<"ARREGLO: (";
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        cout<<P_array[i]<<",";
    }
    cout<<")";
}
void Ej::ingreso_arreglo()
{
    char s[55];
    bool b1=false, b2=false, b3=false, band=true;
    int aux, tam, cont=0;;
    cout<<"********************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<"EJECUTANDO..."<<endl;
    cout<<"********************************************"<<endl<<endl;
    Sleep(500);
    cout<<"\t BIENVENIDO"<<endl;
    // <LECTURA DEL TAMAÑO DEL ARREGLO>
    do
    {
    cout<<"EMPECEMOS POR DECIRME EL TAMAÑO DEL ARREGLO A UTILIZAR..."<<endl<<">"; cin.getline(s,55);
    if(s[0]>=64 && s[0]<=90) b2=true;
    if(s[0]>=97 && s[0]<=122) b3=true;
    if(b2 || b3)
      {
      cout<<endl<<"VALOR INTRODUCIDO DE ORIGEN NO NUMERICO, INTRODUZCA UN ENTERO VALIDO...."<<endl;
      b1=true;
      }
    aux=atoi(s);
    if(aux!=0) b1=false;
    b2=false;
    b3=false;
    }while(b1);
    // </LECTURA DEL TAMAÑO DEL ARREGLO>
    tam=atoi(s);//ASIGNACION DEL TAMAÑO UwU
    SetN(tam);
    b1=true;
    // <LECTURA DE ENTEROS PARA SU POSTERIOR ASIGNACION AL ARREGLO...>
    cout<<"********************************************";
    cout<<endl<<"AHORA QUE DECIDIO EL TAMAÑO, POR FAVOR RELLENE EL ARREGLO..."<<endl;
    cout<<"********************************************"<<endl<<endl;
    for(int i=1; band ;i++)
    {
        
        do
        {
        cout<<"INTRODUZCA EL VALOR DEL ENTERO EN EL INDICE #"<<cont<<"...." <<endl<<">"; cin.getline(s,55);
        if(s[0]>=64 && s[0]<=90) b2=true;
        if(s[0]>=97 && s[0]<=122) b3=true;
        if(b2 || b3)
        {
        cout<<endl<<"VALOR INTRODUCIDO DE ORIGEN NO NUMERICO, INTRODUZCA UN ENTERO VALIDO...."<<endl<<endl;
        b1=true;
        i=0;
        }
        aux=atoi(s);
        
        if(aux!=0)
        {
        P_array.push_back(atoi(s));
        b1=false;
        }
        if(i==tam)band=false;
        b2=false;
        b3=false;
        }while(b1);
        cont++;
    }
    
    // </LECTURA DE ENTEROS PARA SU POSTERIOR ASIGNACION AL ARREGLO...>
    
    
    
    
    
    
}
int ExisteElemento(int n[],int x,int i)
{
    int indice;
    if(n[i]==x) return indice;
    else indice = ExisteElemento(n,x,i++);
    return indice;
}
int Ej::Ocurrencia(int n, int posicInc)
{
     if(posicInc< getN())
     {
            if(n==P_array[posicInc]) return 1+Ocurrencia(n,posicInc+1);
            else
            return Ocurrencia(n, posicInc+1);
      }

}
int Ej::Suma(int array[], int x)
{
    //x=3;
        int sum;
        int tam = x;
        if (tam == 0) return array[tam];
        else sum = (array[tam]) + Suma(array, tam - 1); 
        return sum;
}
int Ej::menu()
{
    char aux[55]="";
    int a;
    cout<< "[ 1 ] - - - - - - - - - Ejecutar metodo ExisteElemento."<<endl;
    cout<< "[ 2 ] - - - - - - - - - Ejecutar metodo Ocurrencia."<<endl;
    cout<< "[ 3 ] - - - - - - - - - Ejecutar metodo Suma."<<endl;
    cout<< "[ 4 ] - - - - - - - - - Ejecutar metodo Ordenar."<<endl;
    cout<< "[ 5 ] - - - - - - - - - Salir del Programa."<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese una opcion......."<<endl; cout<<">";
    cin.getline(aux,55); a=atoi(aux); return a;
}
void Ej::Proc_princ()
{
    int aux=0;
    
    int opc=0;
    ingreso_arreglo();
    int bigaux[N];
    get_Assign_Array(bigaux);
    cout<<endl<<"Bigaux: (";
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        cout<<bigaux[i]<<",";
    }
    cout<<")"<<endl<<endl;
    //ABIERTO, COMENZADO RENOVACION...
    
    do
    {
        opc=menu();
        switch(opc)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"EL NUMERO DEL INDICE DONDE SE ENCONTRO EL ELEMENTRO INGRESADO FUE..."<<ExisteElemento(bigaux, 0, ingreso_g())<<endl<<endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                aux=Ocurrencia(ingreso_g(),0);
                cout<<endl<<"LA CANTIDAD DE VECES QUE SE REPITIO EL DATO EN EL ARREGLO FUE DE..."<<aux<<endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                
                 cout<<endl<<"EL RESULTADO DE LA SUMA FUE DE..."<<Suma(bigaux,getN())<<endl<<endl;
              
                break;
            case 4: 
                
                break;
            case 5: 
                break;
            default:
                cout<<endl<<"OPCION INCORRECTA (ᴗ.ᴗ), INTRODUZCA UN PARAMETRO VALIDO ENTRE EL RANGO DE OPCIONES..."<<endl;
        }
    } while(opc!=5);  
}
```

De igual manera me preguntaba la razón por la cual únicamente netbeans me perdona la llamada de `P_princ()`, ya que intenté compilar el programar en Programiz y compiló lo siguiente...

```
invalid use of non-static member function 'void Ej::Proc_princ()'
```

Comment: Lo que te está diciendo el error es que no puedes usar `Proc_princ` como si fuese una función estática porque no lo es. En la pregunta falta justamente la llamada a dicha función, por lo que no es posible solucionar tu problema. En cualquier caso, no creo que sea necesario copiar **todo el código**. Es preferible filtrar y mostrar un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ````
> undefined reference to `Ej::ExisteElemento(int*, int, int)'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status```
> ````

Si vamos a la implementación de la función:

```
int ExisteElemento(int n[],int x,int i)
{
    int indice;
    if(n[i]==x) return indice;
    else indice = ExisteElemento(n,x,i++);
    return indice;
}
```

Vemos que le falta el ámbito de la clase:

```
int Ej::ExisteElemento(int n[],int x,int i)
//  ~~~~ <<--- ESTO
{
    int indice;
    if(n[i]==x) return indice;
    else indice = ExisteElemento(n,x,i++);
    return indice;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro y conciso, te lo traduzco

> ```
> invalid use of non-static member function 'void Ej::Proc_princ()'
> ```

> ```
> uso no válido de función miembro no estática 'void Ej::Proc_princ()'
> ```

Las partes relevantes del error son:

- Función miembro: se refiere a que la función pertenece al ámbito de un objeto.
- No estática: se refiere a que la función miembro requiere una instancia del objeto para ser invocada.
- `'void Ej::Proc_princ()'`: Nos indica que la función miembro no estática es `Proc_princ` perteneciente al objeto `Ej`.

Como puedes ver, el error NO se origina del uso de `ingreso_g()` en los parametros, esa función ni siquiera es mencionada por el compilador. Lo que puedo ver es que el código que genera dicho error no forma parte del (excesivamente) extenso código que has compartido.

Comment: Ok, tendre en cuenta lo de no compartir el codigo entero sin una justificacion, pero me percate que mi pregunta no tenia una parte esencial del problema, no se si podrias darle otra leida u.u